# iterating a list of inherited class c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator, stdlist

I have two classes which inherit from a third class, and they are stored in a list.

I'm trying to iterate that list and call the implemented function of each class, however, the code doesn't compile.

Here is my code:

```
class A
{   
   public:

   virtual void foo ()=0;
};

class B :public class A
{
   public:

   void foo();
}

class C :public class A
{
   public:

   void foo();
}

std::list<A*> listOfClasses;

listOfClasses.push_back (new B());
listOfClasses.push_back (new C());

for(std::list<A*>::iterator listIter = listOfClasses.begin(); listIter != listOfClasses.end(); listIter++)
{
    listIter->foo()
}
```

This code doesn't compile, I'm getting the following error message (`for the line listIter->foo()`):

`'foo' : is not a member of 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'`

Any ideas why?

Comment: try `(*listiter)->foo()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container holds pointers, so you need to de-reference them:

```
(*listIter)->foo();
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the iterator this way: `(*listIter)->foo()`

Comment: This is because the iterator acts like a pointer, and what it points to is a pointer. So there are two levels of indirection.

Answer (score 3):

You need to dereference the iterator first:

```
(*listIter)->foo()
```

Answer (score 3):

For some variety, here's a simpler alternative syntax for C++11, that avoids this issue altogether:

```
for (auto p : listOfClasses)
{
    p->foo();
}
```